# Type 'RgbaObject[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'

Tags: typescript, typeerror

I have an array of hex values:

```
const presetColors = [
    '#E91E63',
    '#FF8A65',
    '#F8E71C',
    '#697689',
    '#37D67A',
    '#D9E3F0',
    '#BD10E0',
    '#9013FE',
    '#4A90E2',
    '#50E3C2',
    '#000000',
    '#4A4A4A',
    '#FFFFFF',
]
```

And I am using a library https://github.com/sindresorhus/hex-rgb that converts hex to rgb.

I have a `SwatchesPicker` function that accepts `presetColors`:

```
type SwatchesPickerProps = {
    color: string
    onChange: (newColor: string) => void
    presetColors: Array<string>
}

const SwatchesPicker = ({ color, onChange, presetColors }: SwatchesPickerProps) => {
    return null;
}

<SwatchesPicker
  color={color}
  onChange={setColor}
  presetColors={presetColors.map((color) => hexRgb(color))}
/>
```

Now I get an error on `presetColors` stating:

> Type 'RgbaObject[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
> Type 'RgbaObject' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

The reason is `hexRgb(color)` returns `RgbaObject[]` & `presetColors` accepts `string[]`.

So how do I convert `RgbaObject[]` to `string[]`?

Comment: How does a string with rgb should look like? Did you try to pass options `{format: 'css'}` to hexRgb?

Comment: If you have an object `{red: 205, green: 34, blue: 34, alpha: 0.8}` and you wish to represent it to string you need to determine how this string should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple `hex2rgb` function as [hex-rgb](https://github.com/sindresorhus/hex-rgb) returns `{ red: number, green: number, blue: number, alpha: number}`.

And the library I use for color picker called [react-colorful](https://github.com/omgovich/react-colorful) needs `{ r: number, g: number, b: number, a: number}` as an input so the following function does just that.

```
import hexRgb from 'hex-rgb'

export const hex2rgb = (color: string) => {
    const { red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a } = hexRgb(color)
    return { r, g, b, a }
}
```

Then I converted all `string` to `Rgba`:

```
type Rgba = {
    r: number
    g: number
    b: number
    a: number
}

type SwatchesPickerProps = {
    color: Rgba
    onChange: (newColor: Rgba) => void
    presetColors: Array<Rgba>
}

<SwatchesPicker color={color} onChange={setColor} presetColors={presetColors.map(hex2rgb)} />
```

And this did the trick :)